# Identity without individual user accounts in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-identity, session-cookies, identity

I am developing an ASP.NET 5 web application which allows users to play chess anonymously (without creating an account) against each other.

I need to maintain the state for the individual user during the game, what is the best way to achieve this?

Is there a way to configure ASP.NET Identity for the needs of my application?
Or should I use sessions? Or something else?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in ASP.NET is to use Cookies, which allow you to have the user save their session state on their end. Here is the [ASP.NET Cookies Overview on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx), which covers everything you will need to know to get started.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will use cookies as you suggested.